# youtube.com/iframe_api do not fire in IE11 or Edge in Windows 10

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have implemented iframe_api for youtube clips on my site with following code.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Setup Youtube player
var player;

// Get id of first clip
var ytVideoId = jQuery('.start-yt').attr('data-video-id');

// When API is ready, create player with above id
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: ytVideoId,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
    console.log('API Ready');
}

// When player is ready
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    jQuery('.start-yt').addClass('play-icon');

    // Set glob var
    var ytGlobId ="";

    // Close button
    jQuery('.ytClose').click(function(){
        jQuery('.youtube-player-container').removeClass('active');
        player.pauseVideo();
    });

    jQuery('.youtube-player-container').click(function(){
        jQuery('.youtube-player-container').removeClass('active');
        player.pauseVideo();
    });

    // load or play clip
    jQuery('.start-yt').click(function(){
        jQuery('.youtube-player-container').addClass('active');

        if (ytGlobId == jQuery(this).attr('data-video-id')) {
            player.playVideo();
        } else {
            ytGlobId = jQuery(this).attr('data-video-id');
            player.loadVideoById(ytGlobId);
        }
    });

    console.log('Player Ready');
}
```

This *works*. But a friend have Windows 10 and IE11 + Edge. And it seems that `'onReady': onPlayerReady` do not fire there. `console.log` do write `API Ready` but not `Player Ready` when we have checked. It gives no error in the console, it just do not fire and works. I have checked in Browserstack with the same combinations (Windows 10 + IE11/Edge) and there it seems to work.

I have searched google for answers, and it seems some people have had similar problems, but I have not found an example exact enough to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596571/onready-event-not-firing-on-ie11), there is a temporary issue with the IFrame API. There was a temporary issue with the iFrame Player API (which was fixed in June 2013) that you can read in this [link](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4706).

As a temporary fix, you just need to add the event listener within the `onReady` event:

```
function onReady() {
    player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {
        console.log('State is:', e.data);
    });
}
```

Here's another thread which might also help: [Youtube Iframe API not working in Internet Explorer (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234788/youtube-iframe-api-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: Thanks @abielita. Tried it out, but it did not work.

Comment: All I should need to do is to att that eventlistner with just a console.log message? After I did that I get error in Chrome `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://dev3.axiell.com').`, but the player is working. But still no difference in Edge/IE11, it still fails. I also tried to place my functionality within the eventlistner, but that crashed the player in all browsers.

Comment: sorry for many splitted comments about the same thing. As I see it, the problem is that function `onReady()` never even gets called at all. So placing eventlistner within it makes no difference since `onReady()` never fires at all in Win10 + Edge/IE11.